# How to copy two function-connected drop down buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a program where I can copy a div over and over again, which contains two drop down buttons and to input forms. Copying a div with its elements is already solved, the problem is that this div contains two drop down buttons which are connected by a function: when one button option is selected, the other one shows respective choices. So copying a div with these two drop down buttons work, but they aren't connected anymore. How do I declare that for every new div the function ChangeCarList will work with those two only ir particular div? Sorry for a messy formulation, but here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  

<div id="Item1">

<select id="car" onchange="ChangeCarList()">
  <option value="">-- Car --</option>
  <option value="VO">Volvo</option>
  <option value="VW">Volkswagen</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>

<select id="carmodel"></select>
<input type="text" value="number1">
<input type="text" value="number2">

<TD width="200" rowspan="3" valign="top"></STRONG><span style="color: #ff0000">*</span>
<input type="button" name="" id="" value="+" onclick="addItem('Item1');" style="20;" class="FieldBlack"></input>
<input type="button" name="" id="" value="-" onclick="parentNode.remove()" class="FieldBlack"></input>
</TD>
</div>

<script>

function addItem(div)
{

var ediv=document.getElementById("Item1");
var temp=ediv.innerHTML;
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
var divIdName=div+1;//i hav taken 1 for sample for adding id to the div
newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
newdiv.innerHTML =temp;
ediv.parentNode.insertBefore(newdiv, ediv.nextSibling);
}
var carsAndModels = {};
carsAndModels['VO'] = ['V70', 'XC60', 'XC90'];
carsAndModels['VW'] = ['Golf', 'Polo', 'Scirocco', 'Touareg'];
carsAndModels['BMW'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

function ChangeCarList() {
    var carList = document.getElementById("car");
    var modelList = document.getElementById("carmodel");
    var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (modelList.options.length) {
        modelList.remove(0);
    }
    var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
    if (cars) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            var car = new Option(cars[i], i);
            modelList.options.add(car);
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
function ChangeCarList() {
    var carList = event.target;
    console.log(carList);
    var modelList = carList.parentNode.querySelectorAll('select')[1];
    var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (modelList.options.length) {
        modelList.remove(0);
    }
    var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
    if (cars) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            var car = new Option(cars[i], i);
            modelList.options.add(car);
        }
    }
}
```

**RE-EDIT FUll VerSIOn**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  

<div id="cars">
<div id="Item1">

<select id="car" onchange="ChangeCarList()">
  <option value="">-- Car --</option>
  <option value="VO">Volvo</option>
  <option value="VW">Volkswagen</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>

<select id="carmodel"></select>
<input type="text" value="number1">
<input type="text" value="number2">

<TD width="200" rowspan="3" valign="top"></STRONG><span style="color: #ff0000">*</span>
<input type="button" name="" id="" value="+" onclick="addItem('Item1');" style="20;" class="FieldBlack"></input>
<input type="button" name="" id="" value="-" onclick="parentNode.remove()" class="FieldBlack"></input>
</TD>
</div>
</div>
<script>

function addItem(div)
{

var ediv=document.getElementById("Item1");
var temp=ediv.innerHTML;
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
var divIdName=div+1;//i hav taken 1 for sample for adding id to the div
newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
newdiv.innerHTML =temp;
document.getElementById('cars').appendChild(newdiv);
}
var carsAndModels = {};
carsAndModels['VO'] = ['V70', 'XC60', 'XC90'];
carsAndModels['VW'] = ['Golf', 'Polo', 'Scirocco', 'Touareg'];
carsAndModels['BMW'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

function ChangeCarList() {
    var carList = event.target;
    console.log(carList);
    var modelList = carList.parentNode.querySelectorAll('select')[1];
    var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (modelList.options.length) {
        modelList.remove(0);
    }
    var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
    if (cars) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            var car = new Option(cars[i], i);
            modelList.options.add(car);
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but doesn't seem to work. I can't spot the problem.

Comment: sorry i tested on chrome it works without sending event paramenter.
make 2 quick changes 
HTML
**<select id="car" onchange="ChangeCarList(event)">**
&&
JS 
**function ChangeCarList(event)**

Make these changes so it will working on all browsers